# Is it safe to use wall-socket -> USB chargers to charge any USB device?

Tags: usb, charging

Specifically, the charging unit that came with my HP Touchpad is a wall-plug unit with a female USB adapter on the other side ([e.g. this pic on pcmag.com)](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow_viewer/0,3253,l%253D266309%2526a%253D266303%2526po%253D23,00.asp?p=n).  Will this work for anything that charges with USB (my thought being the USB voltage/current rating is standard?)  For example, I have a [wireless headset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VANOFY) that charges via USB on my computer, could I use the wall adapter for that without damaging the battery on the wireless headset?

Comment: The only real issue is whether the charger is reasonably well regulated and therefore safe for the device.  But building these things is so standardized now, it's unlikely that a bad-by-design unit would be floating about.  (There's always the possibility of a single unit going wonky, of course, and that's a bit more likely than your laptop USB port going wonky, but not by much.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HP TouchPad charger has output of 5.3V at 2.0A. My Nokia phone charger's output is 5.0V at 1.2A. and TouchPad complains of insufficient current for charging when connected to it or to a computer. At the same time, I've charged the phone off the TouchPad charger a few times without any issues so far although I was worried that the higher current could damage it.

Comment: Using a higher current charger to charge a lower required current device won't harm anything, the device will only draw what it needs, in this case 1.2A of the capable 2.0A. But the insufficient current is because its too low to charge the HP from the Nokia charger. It can only supply 1.2 where the HP needs the full 2A.

Comment: If 5.0V is the standard, wouldn't the output on the HP charger of 5.3V be a problem?

Comment: @CoolUserName - No

Comment: @Ramhound Very interesting. Why not?  Is there an acceptable tolerance window for USB?  Is it just that electronics themselves have a big enough tolerance window?

Comment: @Paul - You are replying to a 11+ year old comment.

Answer (score 6):

As long the adapter has 5 volt output (which is the usb-standard) you could not damage your device.

However, some devices [won't charge with those adapters.](http://anythingbutipod.com/2009/08/usb-charging-guide/)